# Php autoload project

Tags: php, include, project, require, autoload

I've a project like this:

[image: project]

Now i want to autoload all the php files in the folder classes and sub folders.

I can do that with this:

```
$dirs = array(
   CMS_ROOT.'/classes',
   CMS_ROOT.'/classes/layout',
   CMS_ROOT.'/classes/layout/pages'
);
foreach( $array as $dir) {
  foreach ( glob( $dir."/*.php" ) as $filename ) {
    require_once $filename;
  }
}
```

But i dont like this. For example.

> "layout/pages/a.php" extends "layout/pages/b.php"

Now i get an error because a.php was loaded first. How do you people load your project files? Classes?

SOLVED :)

This is my code now:

```
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
function autoloader($className) {
    $className = str_replace('cms_', '', $className);
    $className = str_replace('_', '/', $className);

    $file = CLASSES.'/'.$className.'.php';
    if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
    require_once $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of "autoloading": http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php - this resource might be also helpful: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Comment: Well if you just run straight into the wall, it's not always nice. Probably take a look into the PHP manual first, see also http://php.net/spl_autoload_register and think about how you want to map class-names to file-names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register('your_autoloader');

function your_autoloader($classname) {
    static $dirs = array(
      CMS_ROOT.'/classes',
      CMS_ROOT.'/classes/layout',
      CMS_ROOT.'/classes/layout/pages'
   );
   foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
      if (file_exists($dir . '/'. $classname. '.php')) {
          include_once $dir . '/' . $classname . '.php';
      }
   }
}
```

After registering `your_autoloader` with `spl_autoload_register()` it will be called by the php interpreter every time you access a class that:

- Has not already been loaded with `require_once()` or `include_once()`
- Is not part of the PHP internals

Comment: Thanks! That was a stupid question from me. I could figure it out for myself but had no time for that. Many thanks hek2mgl! :)